# How to import data from CSV file into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I have to import data from a CSV file into MySQL database using JSP/Servlet. While searching I got [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499440/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-mysql-from-an-hibernatespring-application)! where it is said that we can use MySQL command "LOAD DATA INFILE ..." in hibernates createSQLQuery.

But in my case the table in which I need to upload the data is distributed on multiple database server. I would be getting a API through which I would get the connection to the database.

My query is, where should I save the CSV file -- in my tomcat server or on the system where I would be executing the "LOAD DATA INFILE ..." command.

Comment: To mark a question as answered, just set an accepted answer, do not put "Solved" in title like as you would do in an old fashioned discussion forum. This makes no sense. Stack Overflow is a Question & Answer site already. Questions with accepted answers already appear differently in the listing and are searchable by `accepted:1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV file should be saved on server running MySQL DB. Also access privileges should be set that the user which MySQL Server is run under is allowed to access this file.

You might also find [article on LOAD DATA INFILE from MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I would be getting only the connection to that database. I would not have access to save the file on that system. Is there any way to directly load the CSV data into MySQL database?

Comment: Unfortunately, no (at least, not that I'm aware of). You'll have to either parse CSV on client or write a stored procedure that will do parsing of incoming text on DB level. I'd suggest parsing on client, MySQL server seems to be not very fast and/or efficient in string manipulations. If anyone knows the other way, I'd be glad to learn it.

Comment: UPDATE: MySQL docs say it's possible to specify `LOCAL` keyword after `LOAD DATA` - it will force client to read file from client filesystem, pass it to server (it will be saved in server /tmp or other temporary directory) and read by using usual `LOAD DATA` statement. So you should do `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file_name' INTO ...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check it an let you know the result.

Comment: Thanks '@Sergey' your suggestion of using the 'LOCAL' keyword in 'LOAD DATA' works charmingly.